# clang sanitizers incorrectly catching integer overflow

Tags: c++, clang, sanitizer

Say my `size_type` is `uint64_t`, and I have the following loop (where `sz` is of `size_type` too)

```
for ( size_type i= 0; i < sz; ++i ) {
     //something
     if ( i+1 == sz ) { //<-- here
         ///
     }
}
```

Now when compiling this with flags `-fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=undefined -O2 -fsanitize=address`, I get a runtime error which says that in the place I marked `here` in the code snippet above, `2147483647 + 1 cannot fit into integer`, and it is true that `sz` is something tad larger than `2^31-1`. However, everything should be OK, beause `uint64_t` can hold the value, and by conversion rules `i+1` should be promoted to `uint64_t`. What am I missing? 
EDIT: Isn't it so that `uint64_t` always has `64` bits? Then, `2147...`-value is just `32` bits, and we should still be OK. I'm now running my thing without sanitizers, and no crash has occurred so far.
EDIT:

> clang version 8.0.0-3~ubuntu18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_800/final) Target:
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix

and also I have linker flags as follows

```
set (CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address")
```

maybe that is interfering as well? I 
know the compiler explorer cannot reproduce the error, which is strange and calls for further investigation on my part.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: which version of clang are you using?

Comment: I'm assuming that you get the same ssue without `-fsanitize=address`, in which case I can't repro: https://godbolt.org/z/4hygZE (Also note that two or more people have just had to turn your code snippet into something that can actually compile and run. It would save everyone a lot of time if you provided that yourself - even more so because we wouldn't be stuck looking at code that doesn't actually reproduce the issue.)

Comment: What abut checking this `if ( i == sz - 1 )`? As long as `sz > 0` this should be fine and no overflow of `i` should occur

Answer (score 0):

During the last iteration `i = UINT64_MAX - 1`, so `i+1 = UINT64_MAX`, so `i <= UINT64_MAX` in all cases.

```
for ( size_type i= 0; i < sz; ++i ) {
     //something
     if ( i+1 == sz ) { //<-- here
         ///
     }
}
```

There's no overflow. There's a possibility of bug in clang where it is trying to do incorrect induction variable optimization.

clang-8, rcx is incremented until it reaches 0. This may have introduced **off by 1** error.

```
.LBB1_4:
        neg     rcx 
.LBB1_5:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     rax, rdi 
        jne     .LBB1_7
        mov     qword ptr [rsp - 8], rdi 
.LBB1_7:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB1_5 Depth=1
        add     rdi, 1
        inc     rcx 
        jne     .LBB1_5
.LBB1_8:
```

while clang-9. The `rcx` is decremented until it reaches 0.

```
.LBB1_7:
        ret 
.LBB1_6:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB1_4 Depth=1
        add     rdi, 1
        add     rcx, -1
        je      .LBB1_7
.LBB1_4:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        cmp     rax, rdi 
        jne     .LBB1_6
        mov     qword ptr [rsp - 8], rdi 
        jmp     .LBB1_6
```